# Can't install laravel packages, symfony/process has wrong version

Tags: symfony, laravel, laravel-5, package, symfony-process

I tried to install some packages that need a 2.* version but the new laravel version uses 3.*

Is there any way to "downgrade" the package or do I have to wait until the packages are updated to the latest version?

Comment: In general your options are to either wait for the package to be updated to support v3.x or downgrade Laravel versions to one that uses the v2.x. If we know what package you're trying to install then perhaps there may be a beta/dev version you can install that supports v3.x

Comment: I am trying to install https://github.com/backup-manager/laravel. I opened a new issue and the author said he would update it as soon as possible.

Comment: Ah okay. Looks like you'll just have to wait for the author to update as even the dev version of the package still uses 2.*.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, when I wanted to install sclable/php-latex. It needed symfony process higher than 2.7. Installed was version 3.x.
I thought, everything should be fine, but it did not work.

You just have to modify your composer.json file and set the version higher than 2.

`"symfony/process": "^2.7"`

as here my composer.json file

```
{
  "name": "laravel/laravel",
  "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
  "keywords": [ "framework", "laravel" ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "type": "project",
  "minimum-stability": "beta",
  "prefer-stable": true,
  "require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
    "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^2.2",
    "symfony/process": "^2.7",
    "sclable/php-latex": "0.*",
    "anahkiasen/former": "^4.0"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
    "symfony/css-selector": "2.8.*|3.0.*",
    "symfony/dom-crawler": "2.8.*|3.0.*"
  },
```

Then make an composer update:

```
composer update -verbose
```